# Data Quality - Is SOUNDEX the solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I work for an organization that has a serious data quality problem with names. There are fifteen databases that contain information about people.  For example:

```
Database 1
Name=Fre&d Blo-ggs DOB 01/01/1980

Database 2
Name=Freddy Bloggs DOB 01/01/1980
```

If a user searches for Fred Bloggs using my search tool then I want both records to be found.  I was thinking about something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Soundex('Fred Bloggs') = Soundex('Fre&d Blo-ggs')
```

Is it advisable to use Soundex like this rather than using replace statements like this:

```
select Replace(Replace(Replace(Name,',',''),'&',''),'@') from Person
 where Replace(Replace(Replace(Name,',',''),'&',''),'@') = @Name
```

@Name is the variable passed in.  Is there a better way of doing it e.g. using regular expressions? Does Soundex affect performance.

Comment: There is a newer version of the SOUNDEX called Metaphone and another called Double Metaphone. These are not implemented in SQL Server by default. They will both provide you a better way to match names by pronunciation rules. They won't help you with bad data.

Answer (score 2):

Nice idea. I would not suggest using it though. I suppose that "John Right" is not the same as "John Write", even though they hear the same. I mean that in the end, what it matters is what you want to compare.... If you want to compare if the name **sounds** are the same, then `SOUNDEX` is fine.

However, I would suggest correcting your data somehow. This would be a real solution, although I can imagine that is not an easy one.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks.  Would you suggest using REPLACE statements as per the original post? +1 for suggesting correcting the data as I know it is the long term solution.  It will not be possible in the short term though.

Answer (score 2):

If soundex is better than regex depends of your data. For example there are different soundex versions for different languages. You have to check with your data, which is better..

Of course soundex does affect performance as any other additional functions you are calling. If performance becomes a problem, I would advise to add an additional column with the already computed soundex or normalized names and to create an index over it.

From own experience I think a normalized / simplified search criterion as e.g. parts of surname, prename and month of birth date should be sufficient to get all persons, but not too many, so a user can decide which person (s)he really wants to choose.

Comment: +1 for the computed data column.  Would you suggest using REPLACE statements to compute?

Comment: Depends probably how many replace you use. Best to test with your real data.

Answer (score 1):

Soundex wont help you. you will stuck if a consonant appears in the name by mistake.

Its better you go for string distance and specify a percentage. A kind of fuzzy matching.

Have a look at the below link for fuzzy matching using levenshtein edit distance algorithm.
[Levenshtein edit distance - MS SQL SERVER](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/fuzzy-string-matching-using-levenshtein-distance-sql-server.aspx)